# Closedness of $\{ s>0 \:|\: \mathbf{x}(t+s)=\mathbf{x}(t) \text{ for all } t\in \mathbb{R} \}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently looking at trajectories of solutions to autonomous differential equations. Given a solution $x:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^n$, which is continuous. To prove that the infimum of 
$\{ s>0 \:|\: \mathbf{x}(t+s)=\mathbf{x}(t) \text{ for all } t\in \mathbb{R} \}$ is non-zero, given it's non-empty, requires the fact that the set is closed. How is this shown?

Comment: Isn't the set of natural numbers closed, since the compliment in $\mathbb{R}$ would be the union of all the open intervals, which would be open?

Comment: @ Winther: $\mathbb N$ is closed !

Comment: @Fred Sorry I was thinking compact. Too early in the morning here.

Comment: @Winther No problem, hope you have a great day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S$ be the set in question.

Let $(s_n)$ be a convergent sequence in $S$ with limit $s_0$. We have to show that $s_0 \in S.$

We have

$$x(t+s_0) = \lim_{n \to \infty}x(t+s_n)=\lim_{n \to \infty}x(t)=x(t)$$

for all $t \in \mathbb R.$

Hence $s_0 \in S.$

Comment: I'm convinced. The applications of sequential continuity on relative simple problems surprise me. Thank you so much!